# Sass Mixin for CSS Inherit

Tags: css, sass, inheritance

I've just written this mixin to help solve a few CSS inherit issues for IE7:

```
=inherit($property)
  $property: inherit

  .ie7 &
    $property: expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle.$property)
```

No errors from the compiler but I don't get anything output from it.

I am calling it like so:

```
+inherit(height)
```

Surely for all browsers I should get `height: inherit` and then in a separate bit for IE get `height: expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle.height)`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself using:

```
=inherit($property)
    #{$property}: inherit

    .ie6 &,
    .ie7 &
        #{$property}: expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle.#{$property})
```